# extracting actual numbers and not cutting others

Tags: grep

I have a log file that I'm extracting 7 digit numbers and 5 digit numbers. 
`grep -ao '[0-9][ ]\{7\}' /var/log/Bridge.log.1 | sort | uniq -c`
This works and extracts my 7 digit numbers. 
When I use this one it gives me a mix of the 5 digit numbers and cut off of the 7 digit numbers.

```
grep -ao '[0-9][ ]\{5\}' /var/log/Bridge.log.1 | sort | uniq -c
```

The question is how to add a space in to the end of the 5 digit search.

Comment: Not quite clear - do you want both 5 digit and 7 digit numbers? But no 6 digits?

Answer (score 2):

`[0-9][ ]\{7\}` would match a single digit followed by seven spaces (with GNU `grep`).

What you probably want is something like

```
grep -o -w -E '[0-9]{7}'
```

The `-w` will ensure that you only get complete "words", i.e. that the match is not a substring of a word.  The `-E` enables extended regular expression (needed for `{7}`; using `\{7\}` in a basic regular expression is a GNU-only extension, which you may or may not continue using).

Using `-w` is equivalent to

```
grep -o -E '\<[0-9]{7}\>'
```

where `\<` and `\>` matches the zero-width word boundaries around the "word" that you are looking for.